# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a basic app that converts Fahrenheit to Celsius. I'm testing the app on an actual device and the app crashes and I'm getting this error

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

Xcode is pointing to this line of code

```
            fahrenheitValue = Measurement(value: value, unit: .fahrenheit)
```

Here is the code block

```
@IBAction func fahrenheitFieldEditingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let text = textField.text, let value = Double(text){
        fahrenheitValue = Measurement(value: value, unit: .fahrenheit)
    } else {
        fahrenheitValue = nil
    }
}
```

Can you please point out to where the problem is?

Comment: is there a nil value? Rather post the code for `Measurement` class only can debug

Comment: Please take a look at the updated code